Do web crawlers clear their browser cache?
Suppose you make a website and you forget to set the proper cache control headers, and your index.html is set to be cached and never expire. You fix this, and after clearing your browser cache this will no longer be an issue, but will web crawlers (such as googlebot) take this into account?
If I have an SPA, the web crawlers typically use some sort of browser to index my website. The question is, if they have a previously cached version of my website stored on their servers, and I have updated my website (and disabled caching on index.html), will they index the most recent version of my website?

Web crawlers don't rely on cache headers to determine when they need to re-fetch your page and index a fresh copy of it.  They use their own algorithms that are based on:

How recently they last crawled.
How much crawl capacity they have available.
How fast your site responds to the crawler.
The reputation of your page (in terms of link juice or PageRank.)
How frequently your page has changed historically.

A page at the back of your website that was hasn't been updated since it was created years ago and which doesn't have any external links may only get crawled every few months.
Your home page will probably get crawled at least every two weeks.  If your home page is for a popular national newspaper and you release new headlines to it throughout the day, your home page could get crawled every few minutes.
Every page that search engine bots crawl effectively starts with a cleared cache and empty cookie jar. Your mis-configured cache headers will not in any way change the crawling behavior or prevent search engines from fetching the latest version of your page.
